# Which framework is better for UI Testing React testing library or python robot framework?

Tags: reactjs, testing, robotframework

Can someone please help me with this, Which framework we can use for UI testing i.e React testing library or Python robot framework?
As per my understanding if we are proceeding with multiple data-driven operations python robot framework is better then react testing library.

Answer (score 1):

react-testing-library vs Robot Framework: What are the differences?

react-testing-library: A lightweight solution for testing React components. It is a simple and complete React DOM testing utility that encourage good testing practices. It provides light utility functions on top of react-dom and react-dom/test-utils, in a way that encourages better testing practices; Robot Framework: A test automation framework for acceptance testing and ATDD. It is a generic test automation framework for acceptance testing and acceptance test-driven development. It has easy-to-use tabular test data syntax and it utilizes the keyword-driven testing approach. Its testing capabilities can be extended by test libraries implemented either with Python or Java, and users can create new higher-level keywords from existing ones using the same syntax that is used for creating test cases.

https://stackshare.io/stackups/react-testing-library-vs-robot-frame-work